# Drobo Dashboard isn't finding Drobo FS

Tags: networking, drobo, drobo-fs

I got an email informing me that the Dashboard software as well as the firmware received an update.  I've updated the dashboard fine, but it can't find my Drobo on the network so I can update it.

I've set the Drobo to use a static IP, and there are a handful of DroboApps running on it.  Connecting to the shares are fine (I've been downloading video to it and watching it from my HTPC without a problem).

Why can't the Dashboard connect to my Drobo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know the reason, but restarting the Drobo seems to have fixed it.  After restarting, it popped up in the Dashboard nearly instantly.  Perhaps the extended uptime (on the order of months) had something to do with it.

**EDIT:** Apparently my Drobo was crashing without me knowing.  From the release notes:

> Fixed Drobo Dashboard discovery issue caused by an internal Drobo FS crash.

Comment: Had the same problem and solution